Is there a concept of multidimensional call stacks in computer science?
Had this random thought while running.
If I think of a conventional computer program function execution, I think of piece of paper. The program can only run down the page, it can never go backwards.
It can go left and right within the piece of paper (eg. if statements).
When another function is called, it goes through the paper to another piece of paper below it on the stack.
When that function returns, it returns out the hole it came through.
Another thing it can do is 'throw' it which case it goes up multiple layers of paper until it encounters a catch block.
At this point I'm just describing a call stack.
This got me thinking about whether you 'throw' in a different direction. But of course the throw really only backtracks the path you came on, and the call stack only has one dimension.
We could imagine instead of pieces of paper, each stack frame was a cube, and function invocations go to an adjacent cube, but now we don't have just 'above' and 'below', we also have in front, behind, left and right.
Is there any such concept in computer science? Theoretical or otherwise? I know at this point it's not really a 'stack', but.

(Just imagine the usual way needing to be called throw up - no way!)

I don't think you can find such a thing if you want that navigation should be like in a (say) Euclidean space or anything.
However, when using coroutines, you can "spawn" arbitrarily many calls, and you can both receive information from these calls (over time), and you can send information into them.  Navigation from a spawnee is done via yield and navigation from a spawner is done via send or resume.
Here is an example of a coroutine in Python:
def f1(x):
    i = 0
    while i < x:
        s = yield i
        if s is not None:
            i = s
        else:
            i += 1


f = f1(10)
next(f)     # 0
next(f)     # 1
next(f)     # 2
next(f)     # 3
next(f)     # 4
f.send(1)   # 1
next(f)     # 2
next(f)     # 3
next(f)     # 4

I don't know if this is helpful at all, but it's what your description made me think of.
